# How to display children terms for 3rd or 4th level taxonomy term using views?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

How does one create (in a view) a list of the children (2nd, 3rd **or** 4th level) of a taxonomy vocabulary? In other words, if I want to display ONLY the 3rd level down of a parent term. Is that possible?
Thanks. :)

Comment: Are you using D6 or D7 ?

Comment: It's D7. I am going to try the solution proposed by Molot. :)